# Make javascript button do nothing if nothing has been entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this script which makes a calculation and redirects the user based on his input. I'd like the 'calculate' button to do nothing if nothing has been entered, but I can't figure out how.

My code:

```
          <li class="buttons"><input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="982264" />
      <button id="Button1" onclick="myFunction()">Beste deal berekenen!</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function myFunction() {
        oText =document.getElementById("element_2").value;
        var e = document.getElementById("element_3");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if(strUser == 3){
        window.location.replace("redirectC.html");
        }       
        else if(oText <= 2){
        window.location.replace("redirectA.html");
        }
        else {
        window.location.replace("redirectB.html");


           }
      }
    function validate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }

      //]]>
      </script>
```

Comment: make it `disabled` by default and remove it on `input` `change`

Comment: thanks, where and how do I do this?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: its a bit messy but can be found here: http://pastebin.com/32yt284W

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `input` event and check what you need to check. In my example I check for an empty string.

```
var button = $('button'),
    input = $('input'),
    disabled = true;

input.on('input', function(){
    disabled = input.val() == "" ? true : false;

    button.attr('disabled', disabled);
});
```

Online here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9wwdg4w/